# 400 Bad Request while POSTing json to Flask on openshift

Tags: python, json, flask, openshift

I have read all related SO questions on this but I still keep encountering this error(400 - Bad Request) when posting json to my Flask app running on RedHat's openshift cloud platform.

This is my code:

`flaskapp.py`

```
import os
from datetime import datetime
from flask import Flask, request, flash, url_for, redirect, \
     render_template, abort, send_from_directory

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_pyfile('flaskapp.cfg')

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/<path:resource>')
def serveStaticResource(resource):
    return send_from_directory('static/', resource)

@app.route("/test")
def test():
    return "<strong>It's Alive!</strong>"

@app.route('/mine', methods=['POST'])
def mine():
    content = request.get_json(force=True)
    print content

    return "Success!\n"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This is how my `app.py` looks like

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# This file may be used instead of Apache mod_wsgi to run your python
# web application in a different framework.  A few examples are
# provided (cherrypi, gevent), but this file may be altered to run
# whatever framework is desired - or a completely customized service.
#
import imp
import os
import sys

try:
  virtenv = os.path.join(os.environ.get('OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_DIR','.'), 'virtenv')
  python_version = "python"+str(sys.version_info[0])+"."+str(sys.version_info[1]) 
  os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = os.path.join(virtenv, 'lib', python_version, 'site-packages')
  virtualenv = os.path.join(virtenv, 'bin','activate_this.py')
  if(sys.version_info[0] < 3):
    execfile(virtualenv, dict(__file__=virtualenv))
  else:
    exec(open(virtualenv).read(), dict(__file__=virtualenv))

except IOError:
  pass

#
# IMPORTANT: Put any additional includes below this line.  If placed above this
# line, it's possible required libraries won't be in your searchable path
#


#
#  main():
#
if __name__ == '__main__':
  application = imp.load_source('app', 'flaskapp.py')
  port = application.app.config['PORT']
  ip = application.app.config['IP']
  app_name = application.app.config['APP_NAME']
  host_name = application.app.config['HOST_NAME']

  fwtype="wsgiref"
  for fw in ("gevent", "cherrypy", "flask"):
    try:
      imp.find_module(fw)
      fwtype = fw
    except ImportError:
      pass

  print('Starting WSGIServer type %s on %s:%d ... ' % (fwtype, ip, port))
  if fwtype == "gevent":
    from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer
    WSGIServer((ip, port), application.app).serve_forever()

  elif fwtype == "cherrypy":
    from cherrypy import wsgiserver
    server = wsgiserver.CherryPyWSGIServer(
      (ip, port), application.app, server_name=host_name)
    server.start()

  elif fwtype == "flask":
    from flask import Flask
    server = Flask(__name__)
    server.wsgi_app = application.app
    server.run(host=ip, port=port)

  else:
    from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
    make_server(ip, port, application.app).serve_forever()
```

And this how am posting the data:

> curl -X POST -H "application/json" -d '{"key":"val"}'
>   https://python-bonga.rhcloud.com/mine

**N/B:** This works fine on localhost

Comment: can you run in debug and send full traceback?

Comment: What was the name of the file you put this in? If this was added as ``wsgi.py`` it will not work unless you have set an override environment variable for the name of the WSGI application entry point. If this was added as ``app.py``, you haven't used the environment variable to say what port you should be listening on to customise what port the Flask server will listen on.

Comment: @reptilicus I added ran in debug mode but just nothing more shows up in the logs, even for 500 errors. Just getting `127.8.182.1 - - [25/Dec/2015 05:37:43] "POST /mine HTTP/1.1" 400 -
`

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Am using the standard file structure created by openshift while creating a Flask app as seem above. So my code goes into `flaskapp.py`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that a `POST` using curl without specifying the Content-Type defaults to sending `Content-Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html#POST

And if the (different) mimetype exists in Flask, then the json data becomes unavailable; hence `request.get_json(force=True)` fails.

I therefore changed my code to look for form-data first before anything else

```
if request.form:
   content = [item for item in request.form]
   print "Content:", ''.join(content)
else:
   content = request.get_json(force=True)
   print "Content:", content
```